# Finding longest name with a tie in java

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public void longestName(Scanner console, int num) {
    String longest = "";
    boolean tie = false;

    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        System.out.print("name #" + i + "? " );
        String name = console.next();

        if(name.length() == longest.length()) {
            tie = true;
        } else if(name.length() > longest.length()) {
            tie = false;
            longest = name;
        }
    }

    String capitalized = longest.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
                         longest.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(capitalized + "'s name is longest");

    if(tie)
        System.out.println("(There was a tie!)");
}}
```

The if loop always returns tie as true. How to check a tie only for the longest name?

Answer (score 0):

The `if` returns tie as true only if there are multiple name with same characters and are longest. Or, the tie is false.
Change your code to a runnable class and the test is as below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        longestName(new Scanner(System.in), 3);
    }

    public static void longestName(Scanner console, int num) {

        String longest = "";

        boolean tie = false;

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

            System.out.print("name #" + i + "? ");

            String name = console.next();

            if (name.length() == longest.length()) {

                tie = true;

            } else if (name.length() > longest.length()) {

                tie = false;

                longest = name;

            }

        }

        String capitalized = longest.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +

                longest.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        System.out.println(capitalized + "'s name is longest");

        if (tie)

            System.out.println("(There was a tie!)");
    }
}
```

The input are jordan, tom and bob and the output is as below:

```
name #1? jordan
name #2? tom
name #3? bob
Jordan's name is longest
```

Another test is:

```
name #1? mary
name #2? andy
name #3? tom
Mary's name is longest
(There was a tie!)
```